# Error: Not a statement, how do I resolve this?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm new to java and I have looked up about this error and I'm certain that it doesn't have to do with curly brackets and semicolons. I know that the variable is not within the scope of the method and can't be called but I still can't figure it out.

The error is on line 36.

```
public class Account {
    double balance;

    public Account(double myBalance) {
        balance = myBalanace;
    }
    
    public void checkBalance() {
        System.out.println("Your current balance is " + balance);
    }
    
    public void deposit(double amountToDeposit) {
        double updatedBalance = balance + amountToDeposit;
        balance = updatedBalance;
        System.out.println("You have deposited: $" + amountToDeposit);
        System.out.println("Your balance is now: $" + balance);
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    
    public void withdraw(double amountToWithdraw) {
        double updatedBalance = balance - amountToWithdraw;
        balance = updatedBalance;
        System.out.println("You have made a withdrawal of: $" + amountToWithdraw);
        System.out.println("Your balance is now: $" + balance);
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account myAccount = new Account(420.69);
        System.out.println("Thank you for using our ATM. Your current balance is: $" + myAccount.balance);
        System.out.println("Please select one of the following options.");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1) Withdraw");
        System.out.println("2) Deposit");
        System.out.println(" ");
        myAccount.checkBalance;
    }
}
```

It's basically supposed to be training to better understand numbers and I used an ATM as the scenario to better grasp it. I know that the variable is not in the scope of the method and can't be called but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I'm also very sure it has nothing to do with curly brackets nor semicolons since I know that is usually linked with these types of errors.

Comment: `myAccount.checkBalance;` - `checkBalance()` is a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to call a function you need the name of the function and parentheses following it, with parameters matching the type that the function calls for...

On line 36 you called `checkBalance` incorrectly. It should be `myAccount.checkBalance();`

The parentheses are empty because the function requires no parameters, but still necessary.

---

A few other things to note:

In line 5, you misspelled
`balance = myBalance;` which will give you an error.

Also, this program will not allow user input to withdraw/deposit because you have not created a `Scanner` object.

Hope this will get you started on fixing up this program